# Adicionar projeto já existe ao github

Tags: visual-studio, github

Eu já tenho uma solução criada no github, já criei uma conta também, só quero adicionar meu projeto já feito em um repositório, porém não estou conseguindo.
já adicionei a extensão do github no visual studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu sempre uso esse [site](http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/index.pt_BR.html) como referencia.

crie uma nova pasta, abra-a e execute o comando

```
git init
```

para criar um novo repositório.

crie uma cópia de trabalho em um repositório local executando o comando:

```
git clone /caminho/para/o/repositório
```

quando usar um servidor remoto, seu comando será

```
git clone usuário@servidor:/caminho/para/o/repositório
```

fluxo de trabalho
seus repositórios locais consistem em três "árvores" mantidas pelo git. a primeira delas é sua Working Directory que contém os arquivos vigentes. a segunda Index que funciona como uma área temporária e finalmente a HEAD que aponta para o último `commit` (confirmação) que você fez.

adicionar & confirmar
Você pode propor mudanças (adicioná-las ao Index) usando

```
git add <arquivo>
git add *
```

Este é o primeiro passo no fluxo de trabalho básico do git. Para realmente confirmar estas mudanças (isto é, fazer um commit), use

```
git commit -m "comentários das alterações"
```

Agora o arquivo é enviado para o HEAD, mas ainda não para o repositório remoto.

enviando alterações
Suas alterações agora estão no HEAD da sua cópia de trabalho local. Para enviar estas alterações ao seu repositório remoto, execute

```
git push origin master
```

Altere master para qualquer ramo (branch) desejado, enviando suas alterações para ele.

Se você não clonou um repositório existente e quer conectar seu repositório a um servidor remoto, você deve adicioná-lo com

```
git remote add origin <servidor>
```

Agora você é capaz de enviar suas alterações para o servidor remoto selecionado.

Comment: Obrigado me ajudou muito

Comment: @CezarMdlosci de nada, então vote ;)